# Telegram bot using google apps script doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot, webhooks

here's my code:

```
var apiToken = "token";
var appUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/link/exec";
var apiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+apiToken;
var commands = {
  "/start": commandStart,
};

function setWebhook(){
  var url = apiUrl + "/setWebhook?url="+appUrl;
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(res);
}

function deleteWebhook(){
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl+"/deleteWebhook");
  Logger.log(res);
}

function doPost(e){

  var webhookData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var from = webhookData.message.from.id;
  var text = webhookData.message.text;
  if (text.charAt(0) == "/") {
    commands[text](from);
  } else {
    sendMessage("You said: "+text, from);
  }
}

function doGet(e){
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Method GET not allowed");
}

function sendMessage(txt, receiver) {
  var encoded = encodeURIComponent(txt);
  var url  = apiUrl+"/sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id="+receiver+"&text="+encoded;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response);
}

function commandStart(receiver){
  sendText("Hello, skinbag", receiver);
}
```

I've been trying to make it work for 5 hours now. Everything seems right, but it just doesn't work.
By doesn't work I mean that it doesn't send any messages

But if I change sendMessage method by hard-coding my own id and calling method directly by "execute" button it actually sends me a message

```
function sendMessage() {
  var encoded = encodeURIComponent("SomeMessage");
  var url  = apiUrl+"/sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id="+MyId+"&text="+encoded;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

I think something might be off with doPost() method.
I tried re-establishing webhook by calling "deteleWebhook" and then "setWebhook", I tried simplifying the code to just "doPost" and "sendMessage" with my id (still didn't work), I tried reading docs (didn't find anything), I tried googling a lot.
I just don't know why it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to make it avaiable to everyone when deploying. That was the problem. I made it avaiable to me only

Yes, I am stupid. But maybe it can help someone in the future